# Como saber se meu app está rodando em um emulador?

Tags: javascript, java, android, ios, react-native

Preciso saber se meu app mobile está sendo executado por um dispositivo virtual. Tem alguma função JS ou nativa pra saber isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma função disponibilizada no pacote [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info)

https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#isemulator

```
DeviceInfo.isEmulator().then((isEmulator) => {
   // false se estiver sendo executado em um dispositivo real
});
```